# How to keep the laptop's temperature low without hardware cleaning?

Tags: ubuntu-netbook, cpu, temperature

Last few days I found out that when I open Google Chrome and the laptop's fans start working really hard and I can not touch the mousepad because of heating.

I use Ubuntu 11.10 on my Toshiba A350-22z laptop and monitor CPU and hard drive temperature. Both cores reached 104 Celsius and I read somewhere "if your processor reaches 105 Celsius it harms itself". I cleaned the inside of of laptop a year ago but there is a point when the weather reaches about 20 Celsius there was no problem. I know hardware cleaning is the best solution but how can I solve with another way? I think the problem is related to the hot weather outside. Is there anybody that has the same problem? In addition to Google Chrome, I realized that when I open online video, the processor temperature increases very quickly.

Comment: If your computer is getting *too hot to touch the touchpad*, you seriously have to get it repaired.

Comment: 104C / 219F is insanely hot, you are already suffering performance loss and may damage the machine. The only correct answer is 'Leave it turned off until you can clean it'. At least spray some compressed air through the vents.

Comment: Thanx @TomBrossman that's what i want to hear.I will apply your advice

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter/285681#285681

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it has been a year, then it is time to clean the dust out again, and make sure that the fan is spinning correctly.  If there is no significant dust and the fan is spinning ( at the correct speed ), then you may try removing the heatsink, cleaning and reapplying the thermal paste.

You also might try the boot option `pcie_aspm=force` as some people have reported that helps.  Run `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub` and add that option to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` options, then run `sudo update-grub` and reboot.

Answer (score 3):

I put two books under my laptop (one on each side). The temperature is now around 60 °C (from 72 °C). This is the cheapest solution, just don't cover the holes where the air flows.

Comment: You mean it is all about that's fan.But is there something else about 104C ? Is it normal ? i already use something under laptop.

Comment: I don't know. Here in my dormitory people usually solve the 'noisy laptop' and 'hot laptop' problem with two books as I described above. If you need a picture, I can send you one.

Comment: Thanx for advice but the point of my question was about google chrome.In addition to heat, i can't open facebook on my google chrome.Indeed my problem is with google chrome on ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 2):

Try installing Jupiter power management and setting it to Power Saving to cut the speed of the processor slightly and keep it that little bit cooler:

http://www.webupd8.org/2010/07/jupiter-ubuntu-ppa-hardware-and-power.html

Comment: thanks for advice but i wonder that if it becomes performance losing ?

Answer (score 1):

Rendering video is a processor intensive task and will likely heat up your processor. Perhaps an external fan or chill pad would help with your overheating problems.

Comment: Is it about an external fan ? Can't i solve with a software or like something else ?