# Dell Vostro 3360 laptop gets warm after 12.10 upgrade

Tags: 12.10, cpu, fan

After my yesterday upgrade to Ubuntu 12.10 my laptop (Dell Vostro 3360) gets warm without the CPU fan cooling at all.
At 75° C the fan seems to be off. This will result in serious problems wen running heavier  processes such as video production.

Any suggestions what I can do to solve this?

Thanks :)

Comment: possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/147010/how-to-keep-the-laptops-temperature-low-without-hardware-cleaning it has great solutions. the last solution solved my heat problem which is to install `Jupiter`

Answer (score 0):

Install drivers if available via Additional Drivers (previously called Hardware Drivers) which is now part of software applet interface.

Answer (score -1):

to turn on the fan click the power button(icon thing(top right)/suspend. turn computer back on,click switch user, then login and the fan should turn on and run normaly

this worked for me

ps. you have to do this every time u turn off your computer

sometimes you have to shutdown the computer and try again
i have an acer aspire 5720z so it may not work