# Increase in laptop temperature on dell 3521

Tags: dell, overheating

The temperature of my laptop increases very much while i am using ubuntu.
i think because of the graphic card.
can anyone tell how to lower the temperature. laptop gets discharged in less than 1.5 hrs.

Result of :sensors

> coretemp-isa-0000
>
> Adapter: ISA adapter
>
> Physical id 0:  +79.0°C  (high= +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
>
> Core 0:         +79.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit =+105.0°C)
>
> Core 1:         +81.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit =+105.0°C)

Result of : `lspci`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Panther Point High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point 6 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Panther Point SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Device 6601
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 05)
08:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. Device 0036 (rev 01)
```

Comment: see this http://askubuntu.com/questions/147010/how-to-keep-the-laptops-temperature-low-without-hardware-cleaning

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/251830/how-to-lower-the-hdd-temperature

Comment: GO TO THIS LINK  http://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed

Comment: @Abdul-Rehman controlling fan speed wont solve the issue of heating, even the link you have provided with answer is not working for many peoples like in "/usr/sbin/pwmconfig" there are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed...and sensors results is completely showing the temperature is too high.

Answer (score 1):

Most of times it could be about your graphic card gets warm and because your graphic card is integrated into your cpu the system thinks that cpu gets warm

install `mesa-utils` and `mesa-utils-extras` and reboot  , for installing use the following command-

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils mesa-utils-extra
```

it will work for Intel Graphic Cards

If you are having NVIDIA graphic card then use bumblebee because mesa and NVIDIA will conflict with each other for sure.. to install bumblebee use-

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/testing
```

then for 12.04 and 13.04 use-

```
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia virtualgl linux-headers-generic
```

otherwise  for 13.10 use-

```
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus linux-headers-generi
```

( for newcomes: the `$` before this command is just an indicator that tells this command should be entered in a standard user command shell. if you want to use it just press `<ctrl>+<alt>+<t>` and copy-paste without this dollar mark )

If that doesnt work, try to

1. `Cleaning your laptop`- As might be its because of just that, stopping fan from running  properly.
2. `Update bios` - After updating it can perform good operations like increasing compatibility .That solved my issue.
3. `Update Kernel`

hope the very first suggestion will resolve your problem.

Comment: please see my edit and tell me which one should i use meta-utility or some other?

Comment: use mesa..  as you don’t have NVIDIA , anyways these are just workarounds, there is no perfect answer of this. hope mesa will help you ,after that updating BIOS , and KERNEL is a good idea .

Comment: nice answer and very good.

Comment: @rajagenupula that happened to me once on dell n5010 , and this answer solved it right by after updating BIOS.

Comment: and how to disable a graphic card on every boot.is there any command?

Answer (score 0):

Generally More heat means more processing , more work or more load on processor.we cant conclude always that due to only one device.

Actually more heat comes into the matter of processor and you can cool it by reducing the CPU frequency.

Look at this article : [Linux Temperature](http://www.linuxondesktop.in/2011/03/ubuntu-tips-manage-cpu-tempreature.html) &  [Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=597998)

Answer (score 0):

## Did you try [nbfc](https://github.com/hirschmann/nbfc)

My laptop is an Acer Aspire E5-573G nothing else worked to control its CPU fan, but [nbfc](https://github.com/hirschmann/nbfc/wiki/First-steps). I'm using Ubuntu 18.04. The exact profile for my model is missing, but nbfc worked fine with another similar profile (Acer Aspire E5-575G). If you don't know which profile to use, you can try:
`mono nbfc.exe config -r`

Comment: It's generally frowned upon to spam the same answer to so many questions, even if the answer might be useful.

Comment: @MerlijnSebrechts, sorry. I understand. But I tried and search a lot before found this tool and it can help others users, too.